# I have problems with loading javascripts

Tags: functions, templates, javascript, twitter-bootstrap

[Fitclaw](http://fitclaw.com)

I have problem with loading my css/js files. They're uploaded on ftp but i had to direct them with the whole path including domain because with ../ it didn't worked. That's for CSS. JS doesn't works i don't know why i please you to see the page source and i will upload here the functions.php from the bootstrap theme.

```
<?php

function add_theme_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_stylesheet_uri() . 'http://fitclaw.com/wp-content/themes/Coming%20Soon/js/jquery.js');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() . 'http://fitclaw.com/wp-content/themes/Coming%20Soon/style.css'  );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'loader', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://fitclaw.com/wp-content/themes/Coming%20Soon/css/loader.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome.min', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://fitclaw.com/wp-content/themes/Coming%20Soon/css/font-awesome.min.css');


wp_enqueue_style( 'ie.min', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://fitclaw.com/wp-content/themes/Coming%20Soon/css/ie.css');


    wp_enqueue_style( 'normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://fitclaw.com/wp-content/themes/Coming%20Soon/css/normalize.css');

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.countdown.min.js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://fitclaw.com/wp-content/themes/Coming%20Soon/js/jquery.countdown.min.js',array ( 'jquery' ) );

wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://fitclaw.com/wp-content/themes/Coming%20Soon/js/main.js',array ( 'jquery' ));
wp_enqueue_script( 'plugins', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://fitclaw.com/wp-content/themes/Coming%20Soon/js/plugins.js',array(' jquery '));



}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',  'add_theme_scripts' );


?>
```

This is functions.php and it doesn't work. Thanks for your help

Comment: is this a child theme?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be loading both file/folder names into the queue.

`get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://fitclaw.com/wp-content/themes/Coming%20Soon/js/jquery.js`

should only be:

`get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js'`

And so-on and so-forth.

because `get_template_directory_uri` returns, or should be returning this string for you: `'http://fitclaw.com/wp-content/themes/Coming%20Soon/'`

And you should always try to use those relative paths versus hard-coding them.

Answer (score 0):

NO

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'ie.min', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://fitclaw.com/wp-content/themes/Coming%20Soon/css/ie.css');
```

YES

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'ie.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you echo out you stylesheet directory in you functions.php

```
echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
```

you will be able to see the path that is being returned, you should be using

```
get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/file.js'
```